# Is there a way to guarantee that an ant dependency is run only once?

Tags: ant

My question is similar to [avoiding-re-building-prerequisites-in-ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861569/avoiding-re-building-prerequisites-in-ant), except that my need doesn't involve created objects, but processes invoked, so the solutions discussed there won't work for me. At least I think so - but I'm new to ant.

My situation is that I'm writing a set of ant targets, and I need the lets-call-it *setup* target to be executed once and only once, no matter which target is invoked.  Here's a greatly simplified example:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <project name="Ant_Test" basedir=".">
      <target name="setup">
        <echo message="In setup" />
      </target>
      <target name="do.several" depends="setup">
        <echo message="In do.several, calling do.first" />
        <antcall target="do.first" />
        <echo message="In do.several, calling do.second" />
        <antcall target="do.second" />
      </target>
      <target name="do.first" depends="setup">
        <echo message="In do.first" />
      </target>
      <target name="do.second" depends="setup">
        <echo message="In do.second" />
      </target>
    </project>
```

I need *setup* to be invoked exactly once, regardless of whether *do.several*, *do.first*, or *do.second* are invoked.  With my naive attempt above, invoking do.several results in three calls to *setup*.

I've thought of setting a property (let's call it *setup.has.been.invoked*), and using that to conditionally invoke *setup* from within each target, but it appears that property setting is limited to the scope it's done in, so if in *setup*, I set *setup.has.been.invoked* to true, that value only exists within *setup*.

What am I missing?  Is there a section of the tutorials or online documentation I've skipped?  Any pointers or hints?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should remove the [`antcalls`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html) and add `do.first` and `do.second` as dependencies of `do.several`:

```
<target name="do.several" depends="setup, do.first, do.second">
</target>
```

This will make sure, that `setup` is only called once:

```
setup:
     [echo] In setup

do.first:
     [echo] In do.first

do.second:
     [echo] In do.second

do.several:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Documentation says why a property set in setup does not work with antcall:

> The called target(s) are run in a new project; be aware that this means properties, references, etc. set by called targets will not persist back to the calling project.

Comment: +! for getting rid of the `<antcall>`. `<antcall>` makes David sad...  99% of the time, `<antcall>` is not only unnecessary, but also destroys efficiency of the build system. Developers like using `<antcall>` because they're use to controlling the order of execution. One Ant build.xml file we had called each and every dependency at least 14 times. Ant is a matrix dependency language. You should merely state the dependencies for each task, and let Ant figure out the order.

Answer (score 9):

I just would like to add another possible way to do this.

```
<target name="setup" unless="setup.already.executed">
    <echo message="In setup" />
    <property name="setup.already.executed" value="x" />
</target>
```

This way you run it only once and then instantly set the flag that it was already executed once. Also it doesn't break the "depends" part of your code, since it only runs targets if it is possible/necessary, but it doesn't break the execution of the target dependent target.

Also this is the least amount of change in your scripts.

Edit: 
Explanation of the 'doesn't break the depends part' :

If 'ant do.first do.second' is invoked, it results in setup being called twice even with all targets using setup as a dependency.  That would be a problem if setup is doing things like cloning a repo or other time consuming operations.  This approach works for both cases - i.e. 'ant do.several' or 'ant do.first do.second' .

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to the answers you've already received is to create a custom task container  that makes sure it does not repeat an action.  I have such a custom task in [my personal Antlib](http://wiki.github.com/dwdyer/uncommons-antlib/), but there's a whole load of other junk in there that you probably don't want, so maybe you could just copy [the source](http://github.com/dwdyer/uncommons-antlib/blob/master/src/java/main/org/uncommons/antlib/tasks/Once.java) and add it to your own project.  It looks something like this:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.Task;
import org.apache.tools.ant.TaskContainer;
import org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;

/**
 * Task container to ensure that some set of actions is only performed
 * once per build.  On completion of the actions a property is set that
 * prevents subsequent executions.
 */
public class Once extends Task implements TaskContainer
{
    private final List<Task> tasks = new LinkedList<Task>();

    private String property;

    /**
     * The name of the property to consult in order to determine whether
     * the nested tasks should be performed.  This is a required attribute.
     */
    public void setProperty(String property)
    {
        this.property = property;
    }

    public void addTask(Task task)
    {
        tasks.add(task);
    }     

    @Override
    public void execute() throws BuildException
    {
        if (property == null || property.length() == 0)
        {
            throw new BuildException("Property name must be specified.");
        }
        // If no value is specified, the tasks are performed if the property
        // is set to any value.  If a value is specified, the tasks are only
        // performed if the property matches that value.
        if (getProject().getProperty(property) == null)
        {
            for (Task task : tasks)
            {
                task.perform();
            }
            getProject().setProperty(property, "done");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Dan.  I wasn't aware that a custom TaskContainer was a possibility.  It's clear that I have more reading to do.

Comment: Great work Dan! Cant wait to try out uncommons with Ivy, Hudson and  especially using the maven-ant tasks - makes build, deploy, test much easier. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Targets can have an "unless" element that will skip the target if the property referenced by "unless" is set.

Answer (score 1):

See the difference, between **include** and **import** in the Ant manual. Also use **macrodefs**.

I've slightly adapted your example, you'll need several files:
build.xml, common.xml and macrodef_project_setup.xml

**build.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Ant_Test" basedir="." default="init">

<import file="common.xml"/>

<!-- This target overridden by the one in common.xml -->
<target name="common.init"/>

<target name="setup" depends="init"/>

<target name="do.several" depends="common.setup">
    <echo message="In do.several, calling do.first" />
    <antcall target="do.first" />
    <echo message="In do.several, calling do.second" />
    <antcall target="do.second" />
</target>

<target name="do.first" depends="common.setup">
    <echo message="In do.first" />
</target>
<target name="do.second" depends="common.setup">
    <echo message="In do.second" />
</target>

</project>
```

**common.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="common">

<target name="init">
    <project_setup option="Stack.Over.Flow"/>
</target>

<target name="setup">
</target>

<import file="macrodef_project_setup.xml"/>

</project>
```

**macrodef**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="project_setup" basedir=".">

<macrodef name="project_setup">
        <attribute name="option" default=""/>
        <sequential>

            <!-- some process -->
            <echo>THIS IS MY SETUP OPTION: @{option}</echo>

        </sequential>
</macrodef>

</project>
```

**Output:**

```
ant -p
Buildfile: build.xml
Main targets:

Other targets:

 common.setup
 do.first
 do.second
 do.several
 init
 setup
Default target: init
```

*Default target is now init.*

```
ant
Buildfile: build.xml

Ant_Test.init:
     [echo] In setup initialization
     [echo] THIS IS MY SETUP OPTION: Stack.Over.Flow
```

*But you could still use ant setup.*

```
ant setup
Buildfile: build.xml

Ant_Test.init:
     [echo] In setup initialization 
     [echo] THIS IS MY SETUP OPTION: Stack.Over.Flow
```

*Run it with do.several.*

```
ant do.several
Buildfile: build.xml

Ant_Test.init:
     [echo] In setup initialization 
     [echo] THIS IS MY SETUP OPTION: Stack.Over.Flow

Ant_Test.do.several:
     [echo] In do.several, calling do.first

Ant_Test.do.first:
     [echo] In do.first

     [echo] In do.several, calling do.second

Ant_Test.do.second:
     [echo] In do.second
```

Comment: Thanks, Dean.  That's very impressive.  I will indeed look at include, import, and macrodef in more detail.  Thanks.